# DatePicker en castellano

Tags: android

¿Sabéis si se puede poner el `DatePicker` en español? Es una pijotada pero es que me sale en formato inglés y me gustaría tenerlo en español.

Comment: El widget DatePicker toma el formato que el usuario haya puesto en su dispositivo, cambiar el formato seleccionado por el usuario no suena como una buena idea desde un punto de vista de usabilidad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio el DataPicker coge el idioma del sistema, si quisieras forzar el cambio aunque no suele ser buena idea lo que tienes que hacer es forzar un cambio de Locale. pero repito, no es recomendable.

Aquí (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/1587032) puedes ver como forzar el cambio de Locale:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Entonces entiendo por tu respuesta que si instalo la aplicación en mi móvil el datepicker saldrá en castellano?

Comment: En principio si, es como esta definido el widget mejorar la usabilidad.

Comment: Vale ya he configurado el locale de mi emulador y me sale en castellano. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Red no olvides en marcar la respuesta cómo correcta check verde, así aparecerá como resuelta.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#inputId").datepicker({

    currentText: 'Hoy',
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
    'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
    'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié;', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm'

}).datepicker('show');
```

Comment: OP se refiere al DatePicker de Android y no al de jQuery